# Different Charset in Android OS version

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I am writing an `AES code` for encryption and I realized different version of Android `encrypt` differently. I took sometime to Google and read something about `getBytes()` are subject to the charset in the system therefore the `encrypted` String is different.

I log the info from `Log.i("Charset",Charset.defaultCharset().toString());`

On **Android 2.3** it says:

```
06-26 16:10:33.954: I/Charset(453): Charset[UTF-8]
```

**Android 2.2** it says:

```
06-26 16:05:19.140: I/Charset(737): com.ibm.icu4jni.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]
```

**Android 4.x** says:

```
06-26 15:53:17.770: I/Charset(16957): java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]
```

Android 2.3 and 4.x encrypt/decrypt the string with the same result but 2.2 is different.

What can I do to `getBytes()` to make it consistent to all version?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass encoding to `getBytes()`. Example:

```
String myString = "test";
byte[] bytes = myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

For a list of supported values see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

**EDIT**
I see. But I don't understand why different versions of Android encrypt differently. Even it uses different libraries, the standard should be the same...Weird. Maybe you can try to implement your own `getBytes()` then it will work exactly same on all versions. I found this example: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/java-best-practices-char-to-byte-and.html

Comment: Hi, I know about the passing encoding part. If you look at the output by Charset.defaultCharset(), there are all in UTF-8.

Comment: Hi Caner, interesting. I tried the example from your link using stringToBytesUTFCustom(String str) and they still encrypt/decrypt differently. Unfortunately, I only have 1 physical phone so I cannot confirm why am I getting this result. Hope it is restricted to emulator but it does shows a potential pitfall or is it a potential Android bug?

Comment: I tried on real Android hardware, it seems the same. While this is ok but it will present problem if someone upgrade their phone and use the same app to decrypt files that were encrypted with a different phone using different charset return result.