# SHA256 with RSA signature returns different outputs on various Android devices

Tags: java, android, rsa, digital-signature

I am developping an Android app, and I need to use [java `Signature` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Signature.html) for data authentication.

On each Android device, I can sign data and verify its signature. However, given a definite chunk of data to sign, a definite modulus, a definite private exponent and a definite public exponent, the outputs of my signatures are different, depending on devices. I did try with bunch of devices, and I obtain the same signatures for Android 3.2 and 3.2.1, but a differents for an Android 2.2.x device.

I compute these signature from constant fields that I generated previously using a `KeyFactory` with RSA in a java project. The keysize is 2048bit.

Here is a quote of the code that I use to invoque Signature and Verification.

```java
public byte[] signData(byte[] data, PrivateKey privateKey) throws ... {
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        signature.update(data);
        return signature.sign();
}

public boolean verifyData(byte[] data, byte[] sigBytes, PublicKey publicKey) throws ... {
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initVerify(publicKey);
        signature.update(data);
        return signature.verify(sigBytes);
}
```

If I am not mistaking, the signature using SHA256 with RSA is deterministic. Then how can I explain such a behaviour? Another interesting question, how could I make that work cross-devices, i.e. the signatures would be same, no mather which device I use?

Thank you in advance, Franck!

Comment: The code looks right, although pasting the error handlers was hardly necessary. Make sure the key and the data to be signed are the same.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Yes, I am sure all the inputs of my system are the same. I hard coded them as static final, in a class, containing these constants. I did not link the constant values by convenience.

Comment: Debug step by step. First, calculate SHA256 hashes on all those platforms, and compare those.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev The SHA256 are the same. But how could I debug the `Signature` java-class ? RSA encryption and decryption work, but not signature.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `SHA256withRSA` is completely deterministic.

In theory you could be affected by a bug ([see an example](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Incorrect-Hash-header-gets-added-for-SHA256-in-signed-message-td1463380.html)) in an old modified BouncyCastle library version found on one of the Android versions.  Such a bug might be eliminated if you used `SHA512withRSA` instead, well, at least the referenced one would be.

However, before you start digging into the hash algorithm, check close to home.

Maybe you have obtained your byte array through a call to `String.getBytes`.  This call depends on the default platform encoding which is [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212173/different-charset-in-android-os-version) between Android 2.2 and Android 2.3.  This implies that while your strings are the same in both cases, the byte arrays might not be.

To get encoding under control, and make your code platform independent, specify encoding as a parameter:

```
plainText.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

Failing this, there are a few more tactics to get a platform independent implementation.

- wait until 2.2 with the presumably buggy library dies out
- distribute a known good library (jar) with your software.  If that would be BouncyCastle, you will have problems making sure that your and not Android's classes are loaded.  The solution is called SpongyCastle.
- play with alignment/padding.  Try to make the message length in bytes to be congruent with 0,55, 56 or 63 modulo 64 by adding your own fixed padding and hope that one of these options will start giving portable signatures.  These values are chosen to interact with the outermost part of the suspect algorithm which is padding to 512 bit blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jirka. I changed `SHA256withRSA` to `SHA512withRSA`, but it has not fixed the issue. I still have the same signature for a 3.2.1 and 3.2 android devices, and the emulator (2.1) still gets a different signature. The input is not a `String` but a hardcoded `byte[]`.

Any other idea by any chance?

Comment: I also get the same output as for 3.2.1 and 3.2 with an emulated 4.0.3 device.

Comment: @FranckStudiesCommEng - answer expanded by three routes I'd consider next.

Comment: Thank you Jirka, loading SpongyCastle made it work on both android 2.2 and 3.x/4.x!!!!!!! :-)